# How to retrieve the map task output files

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop2

I am trying to retrieve the map task output so I can use it in another method. But the output is getting flushed even if I set the tmp folder in core-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

you can use chain mapreduce .

Split one job  to more than  two jobs   set the firt output to an other input

BTW you can get the both job outputs